# OAuth and additional parameter

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

The following is an example password grant the service would receive.

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: authorization-server.com

grant_type=password
&username=user@example.com
&password=1234luggage
&client_id=xxxxxxxxxx
&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxx
```

I want to know , according to oAuth standard , am I allowed pass additional parameter? for instance

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: authorization-server.com

grant_type=password
&username=user@example.com
&password=1234luggage
&client_id=xxxxxxxxxx
&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxx
&param1=aaaa
&param2=bbbb
&param3=cccc
```

If yes , can I have a **REQUIRED** additional parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, your Authorization Server may require an additional parameter and reject requests that don't have that. This comes at the cost of not being standards-compliant anymore and being interoperable only with Clients that have a bi-lateral agreement with you on the usage of this parameter.

Comment: It is standards-compliant that I have optional parameter? what about custom error code?